# Django jquery .load() {% url %} to keep DRY

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to make my "Details" link load details from ajax call.

That's why I've decided to use JQuery load() function.

Each link gets own data-offer_id attribute and the same for all links class name.

```
<a href="#" data-offer_id="{{ object.id }}" class="offer_ajax">Details</a>
```

Then, there's a javascript code.

```
$(".offer_ajax").click(function () {
    var url = "/some/url/details/"+ $(this).attr("data-offer_id");
$(this).load(url);
```

Problem is that I'd rather use {% url someviewname object_id %} above for "url" js var.

I could set the url in data-offer_details_url="{% url ... %}" and use `var url = $(this).attr("data-offer_details_url"` instead but is that the only way ?

That's  more code to load if url is really long and many records are displayed ...

Thanks

Comment: Django will process the templates before any JS is run, so you can use whatever templatetags, filters, etc that you want. Just keep in mind that anything added via ajax will not be parsed for Django tags

Answer (score 2):

You should do it like this:

```
<a href="{% url ... %}" class="offer_ajax"/>
```

If you need to have some checks before going to that link, you can use something like this:

```
$('.offer_ajax').click(function() {
    if(!check_if_everything_ok()) {
        return false; // the page won't change
    }
});
```

Also, if you also need the `object.id`, you should also include the `data-offer_id` attribute (and you *won't* repeat yourself by doing that, because the offer id != the offer url)